# How to make wget save the web page contents to a file?

Tags: wget

I'm trying to use wget to save the text of a web page. I run:

```
wget "http://www.finance.yahoo.com/q/op?s=GOOG" > goog.txt
```

to try and save the web page to goog.txt, but instead wget tells me:

```
Saving to: `op?s=GOOG'
```

Why is wget acting like this, and how can I get the expected behavior?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use the `-O` option:

```
wget "http://www.finance.yahoo.com/q/op?s=GOOG" -O goog.txt
```

Comment: And to answer the first part of the question (why): `wget` prints tracing information to standard output and downloads the content to a file whose name is derived from the URL and server response. Also, use `-q` to suppress tracing information.

Answer (score 8):

```
curl "http://www.google.com/" >> /Users/name/desktop/temp.txt
```

Comment: 1. The OP is asking about `wget`, not `curl` (If you expand on why you recommend `curl`, this might be fine). 2. One line answers are often not very helpful. Give some modicum of explanation or elaboration to help enrich everyone's experience.